# Angular material table header text broken to next line

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, mat-table

I have a angular material table where a header text in Chinese is breaking to a new line

[image]

[image]

```
<div class="mat-table-container">
    <div class="mat-table-elevated-wrapper ">
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
            <ng-container matColumnDef="type">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >
                  <span>类型</span>
                </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let call_log">
                  <span>getIcon(call_log.type)</span>
                </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                  <span>名称</span>
                </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let call_log">
                  getName(call_log.name)
                </td>
            </ng-container>
            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; let even = even; columns: displayedColumns"
                [ngClass]="{ 'mat-table-row-color': even, 'call-logs-errors': getErrorRowCondition(row.type) }"></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

The same text in English is "Type". This is not broken, but the Chinese text is broken. What is causing the text to be broken? How can it be solved?

Comment: could you please share english type screenshot?

Comment: @vijay attached screenshot in english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that the width of the type column is making the text go into two rows?
Try adding the following code into your component's css file:

Change "type" into whatever value the **matColumnDef** holds

```
.mat-column-type{
  width: 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
  <span>类型</span>
</mat-header-cell>
```

[image]

Comment: Try this using mat-header-cell element

Comment: Still same issue

Answer (score 0):

```css
.mat-header-cell{
  display: inline
}
/** or **/

.custom-th > span{
  display: inline
}
```

```html
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
  <span>类型</span>
</mat-header-cell>

or

<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="custom-th">
  <span>类型</span>
</mat-header-cell>
```